# Uninstalling chrome apps in the "Show Applications"

Tags: 22.04, uninstall

I have this youtube app installed on my system (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).

[image]

I didn't install it through snap-store or the command line. It was installed when I accepted an option appearing in chrome to install the youtube app. Now I am unable to uninstall it. I am not getting its path through `whereis` command, I have tried *youtube*, *Youtube*, *YouTube* and none work. Is there any way to uninstall it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `chrome://apps` and remove the app. That should uninstall the app from Chrome.

If that still does not remove the launcher in `Show Applications`, remove the desktop shortcut with the YouTube icon in the hidden directory `.local/share/applications` in your home folder.

Comment: Although I had uninstalled chrome, I just put `chrome://apps` in brave and removed YouTube from there.